# If statement with callback design pattern in coffeescript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I would like to do something like this in Coffeescript

```
data = [default, data]
if has_some_data (err, data)->  #has some data hits the db and is a callback
   data = data.get_some_data()
process_data()
```

I would like it so that process data is only called when after the if statement has executed.  Is there a good pattern to do this in CoffeeScript?

Comment: if `has_some_data` is async, how are you using it directly in an `if` statement? Won't you be getting the required data inside the callback?

Comment: Wouldn't "the pattern" be to use `process_data` as the callback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not super-sure that I'm answering your question, but if your question is "How might I write CoffeeScript that accomplishes this goal?" then...

What about using a callback and errback like so:

```
data = {...}
callback = (data) -> process_data(data) if data
errback = (err) -> console.log(err)
has_some_data(args, callback, errback)
```

Otherwise, could you clarify what your constraints are here so I can actually answer your question? ;)